# Cakephp what does $this->request->params['pass'][0] mean?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Hi I need help in this line of code, I already searched in the docs I found `$this->request->params['pass'][0]` but I can't understand what's it's use

What does `$this->request->params['pass'][0]` mean?

Can anyone please help me into this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html

```
$this->request->params['pass']
```

represents the passed parameters within a url

Example:  your request url `localhost/calendars/view/recent/mark`

Both `recent` and `mark` are passed arguments to `CalendarsController::view()`

`$this->request->params['pass']` is an array valued `array ([0]=>recent [1]=>mark)`

So, in the above example

```
$this->request->params['pass'][0] = "recent"
```